# Solve $f^n(x)=4^nx+\frac{4^n-1}{3}$ for $n$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials, p-adic-number-theory

> Solve $y=4^nx+\frac{4^n-1}{3}$ for $n$, where

$n\in\mathbb{N_{\geq0}},$

$y\in2\mathbb{N}_{\geq0}+1$ and

$x\in2\mathbb{N}_{\geq0}+1\setminus(4\mathbb{N}_{\geq0}+1\setminus8\mathbb{N}_{\geq0}+1)$.

In clearer language the process is to start with some odd integer and subtract one and divide by $4$ repeatedly until you hit some number which would take you out of the odd integers if you continued further.

The question asks you to find for any $y$, the closed form for the number of steps $n$ which can be taken.

The end-point of any sequence corresponds with $n=0$ and here $x=y$.  An example is the sequence $\{\ldots213,53,13,3\}$

Comment: Assume the function $f(x)$ is of the form $ax+b$ & then compute $f^{n+1}(x)$.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit that will just take me back where I started!  I constructed this question by building the closed form for $f^n(x)$ where $f(x)=4x+1$. I seek to take some element in the range, and find the closed form for $n$, the number of steps that number is from $f^0(x)=x$

Comment: A recursive definition would be $g(-1)=0, g(1) = 1, g(\text{even x}) = 0, g(\text{non-integer x})=0$ and all other x: $g(x)= 1-((x-1)\%4)/2+((x-3)\%4)/2 \cdot g((x-1)/4)$ where $a\%b\equiv a \mod  b$

Comment: @Χpẘ see my proposed answer below. Any idea if that is correct?

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit do you have anything to say on whether my answer below is correct? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @RobertFrost I am stumped by your notations, usually $f^n$ means either $f\times f\times f\cdots f$ ($n$ times), or $f\circ f\circ f\cdots f$  ($n$ times). Is it the case for some $f$ ?

Comment: @DuchampGérardH.E. sorry yes this is composition $f^2(x)=f(f(x))=f\circ f$ and $f$ is $f(x)=4x+1$

Comment: @RobertFrost Oh, you're right, so taking the OGS should be easy. I put details below if it helps.

Comment: @DuchampGérardH.E. OGS?

Comment: @RobertFrost OGS=ordinary generating series

Comment: @RobertFrost I added the resolution. Is that what you wanted ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking the OGS (ordinary generating series) gives 
$$
\sum_{n\geq 0}(4^n.x+\frac{4^n−1}{3})z^n=(x+\frac{1}{3})\sum_{n\geq 0}(4^n)z^n-\frac{1}{3}\sum_{n\geq 0}z^n=\frac{x+\frac{1}{3}}{1-4z}+\frac{1}{3(1-z)}
$$
from the singularities, you see that $f^n(x)\sim_{+\infty}4^n(x+\frac{1}{3})$ and, in fact, 
$$
f^n(x)+\frac{1}{3}=4^n(x+\frac{1}{3})
$$
so, you get $n$ from $y$ by
$$
n=log_4(\frac{y+\frac{1}{3}}{x+\frac{1}{3}})=\frac{1}{log(4)}log(\frac{y+\frac{1}{3}}{x+\frac{1}{3}})
$$

Is it what you wanted ?

Comment: Thanks. This looks incredibly useful but I'm not familiar with generating functions so I will take a bit of time to digest, plug in a few values and most likely accept in due course.

Comment: @RobertFrost You can skip the OGF part. I just wanted to give my progression, how I came to this simple result, but logically speaking, it can be withdrawn. Just begin at $$
f^n(x)+\frac{1}{3}=4^n(x+\frac{1}{3})
$$

Answer (score 3):

The OEIS sequence [A115362](http://oeis.org/A115362) essentially gives the answer. Closed form is in the eye of the beholder. The generating function you want is
$$ N(y) = \sum_{k=2}^\infty y^{(4^k-1)/3}/(1-y^{2^{2k-1}}) = y^5 + y^{13} + 2y^{21} + y^{29} + y^{37} + y^{45} + 2y^{53} + \dots$$ where the coefficents are the values you want and is essentially equivalent to your $4^nx+\frac{4^n-1}{3}.$

Comment: Thanks, so if I understand correctly the closed form would be $n(y) = \sum_{k\geq0} \frac{y^{4^k}}{1-y^{4^k}}$

Comment: No. I tried to gently suggest that the answer depends on what you allow in "closed form". See the OES entry for more info.

Comment: I can allow 2-adic numbers if we need to sum to infinity

Comment: The simplest answer is in Joerg Arndt formula. So you want $1 +$ the 4-adic valuation of $3n+1$.

Comment: The Joerg Arndt format I already knew!  In fact that was the step which came before finding the closed form for $4x+1$. Have I understood the Frank Ruskey form correctly in my first comment on your answer?  I *think* you're saying I need to take every 3rd value in this series.

Comment: Yes, that is why I wrote $a(3n)$. So what are you still missing?

Comment: Nothing, I'm just a bit slow and I like to be sure I've understood correctly.

Comment: Thank-you for this very helpful answer.  If you edit it (or permit me to do so) to state that $n(y) = \sum_{k\geq0} \frac{(3y)^{4^k}}{1-(3y)^{4^k}}$, assuming I have interpreted correctly, then I can accept.

Comment: $n(1)=0$ because from $1$ you cannot subtract $1$ and divide by $4$ without leaving the odd integers, but your function diverges. $n(5)=1$ because you can take $1$ step (i.e. from $5$ to $1$) before you can go no further. $n(21)=2$ because you can subtract by $1$ and divide by $4$ twice before leaving the integers, taking you from $21$ to $5$ to $1$ but your function of $5$ and $21$ takes on negative values for these: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bk%3D0%7D%5E%5Cinfty+5%5E%7B(4%5Ek-1)%2F3%7D%2F(1-5%5E%7B4%5Ek%7D) Have u perhaps not included the subtraction by $1$ in iteration?

Comment: I have modified my summation to address your comment.

Comment: I'm not going to accept my answer but it was too long for a comment.  I get that. Does that equate to what you put, or has one of us made an error? I put some values into your formula in wolfram alpha and got negative fractions again. Not sure though if that's wolfram's inability to resolve the series.

Answer (score 0):

A115362 gives 1+ the 4-adic valuation of x+1, i.e:

$a(x)=v_4(x+1)+1$

The question asks for $n(y)$, the 4-adic valuation of $3y+1$

$n(y)=v_4(3y+1)$

Substituting to give $n(y)$:

$v_4(3y+1)=a(3y-2)-1$

By OEIS A115362, $a(x)=\sum_{k\geq0}x^{4^k}/(1-x^{4^k})$, therefore:

$$n(y)=\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(3y-2\right)^{4^k}}{1-\left(3y-2\right)^{4^k}}\right)-1$$

EDIT: The above is a generating function for $n(y)$

Comment: Not sure if this is correct ^^

Comment: No it is not. I think you need the difference between a [generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function) and an ordinary function. They are very different and you operate on them iwth different rules. I thnk my generating function coefficients give you what you want.

Comment: @Somos ok thanks that's clearer now. Where you say "it's essentially equivalent" it threw me slightly.  Do you mean it's equivalent to the inverse function of my $f^n(x)$ with respect to $n$?

Comment: Not exactly. My earlier summation terms numerator and denominator were close to your own $4^nx+\frac{4^n-1}{3}$ but even now my $y^{(4^k-1)/3}/(1-y^{2^{2k-1}})$ is similar because of the $(4^n-1)/3$.

Comment: @Somos please forgive my slowness in accepting your answer... it's entirely down to my slowness in understanding it.

Comment: @Somos https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2364138/what-is-a-generating-function